# Restoring from pg_dump with foreign key constraints

Tags: postgresql, restore, foreign-key, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump

In restoring a database from a `pg_dump`, a number of errors are being generated and the whole table is subsequently being ignored.  An example:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "channelproducts" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_dfaae373a5"
DETAIL:  Key (channel_id)=(1) is not present in table "channels".
```

Interestingly enough, I've noted that all these instances are popping up because of the sequence of loading. `channels` is after `channelproducts` both alphabetically and in the file and thus I can understand why postgres complains about having to create a child without a parent.

*caveat: the foreign key is being generated automatically by rails 4.2: I could remove the problem at the source but that still does not really solve the problem...*

version: PostgreSQL 9.4.4.

How can one then restore from `psql` with cases of foreign key constraints, if the database tables and columns are already created?

---

> How exactly (what parameters) was the backup taken and how exactly are you restoring?

Up to now I've been successfully using a syntactic schema such as `pg_dump app_environment > /archive/yymmdd.sql` then on restore `psql app_environment < /archive/yymmdd.sql`

Comment: The comments you indicated should be an answer have been moved to an answer (with attribution to the original authors as required).

Answer (score 18):

You can put `SET session_replication_role = replica;`at the top of your SQL file. This will ignore constraints during data insertion As the setting is session-based, constraints will continue to work outside this script.

**But beware: if you create inconsistent data while this setting is active, postgres will keep them. Constraints are only ever checked at insert/update time.**

See https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/postgres-sessionreplication-role for a deeper discussion of the pros and cons of this approach.

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! This setting is designed for very low-level tools that need to be able to disable system rules, triggers and constraints in Postgres while they do their work. End users should never use this.

Comment: Yes, there is danger associated with this setting. But is is there for replication purposes and that IMHO includes restoration of a DB. Therefore I don't see this as an abuse of the setting.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a backup with `pg_dumpall` or `pg_dump` it will create a plain sql backup and use the `COPY` command to inject the data into the relevant tables.

```bash
pg_dumpall -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -U UNAME > cluster_backup.sql
```

```bash
pg_dump -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -d DBNAME -U UNAME > db_backup.sql
```

The `COPY` command is set to read from `stdin` with all the data being written to sdtin in one go.

```sql
COPY public.enduser (id, name) FROM stdin;
f659b7f9-813a-436b-89e4-e39abcf9fee7    asdf
35239537-e1f2-4cd5-8ef2-4dca5a94985c    ghij
e48f6e42-10e7-4805-a22d-693c39c56900    zxcv
39609d84-fb0f-4acf-adc6-1753f50e905d    yuiop
\.
```

If any of the entries fed to the single `COPY` command fails, all of them fail. A failure occurs if a given entry already exists in the given table.

If you manually edit the backup sql file and duplicate the `COPY` command, along with the delimeter for the input stream, for each entry it will succeed despite some entries already existing in the table. This is obviously impractical.

```sql
COPY public.enduser (id, name) FROM stdin;
f659b7f9-813a-436b-89e4-e39abcf9fee7    asdf
\.
COPY public.enduser (id, name) FROM stdin;
35239537-e1f2-4cd5-8ef2-4dca5a94985c    ghij
\.
COPY public.enduser (id, name) FROM stdin;
e48f6e42-10e7-4805-a22d-693c39c56900    zxcv
\.
COPY public.enduser (id, name) FROM stdin;
39609d84-fb0f-4acf-adc6-1753f50e905d    yuiop
\.
```

A practical solution is to use either of the `--inserts` or `--column-inserts` flags with `pg_dumpall` or `pg_dump`. In this an `INSERT` sql query is created for each entry, instead of a single `COPY` command with all the entries. This is slower (`INSERT` needs to pass by the parser, planner, etc.), but will work regardless of whether your tables already contain some of the data in them.

```bash
pg_dumpall --inserts -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -U UNAME > cluster_backup.sql
```

```bash
pg_dump --inserts -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -d DBNAME -U UNAME > db_backup.sql
```

```sql
INSERT INTO public.enduser VALUES ('f659b7f9-813a-436b-89e4-e39abcf9fee7', 'asdf');
INSERT INTO public.enduser VALUES ('35239537-e1f2-4cd5-8ef2-4dca5a94985c', 'ghij');
INSERT INTO public.enduser VALUES ('e48f6e42-10e7-4805-a22d-693c39c56900', 'zxcv');
INSERT INTO public.enduser VALUES ('39609d84-fb0f-4acf-adc6-1753f50e905d', 'yuiop');
```

```bash
pg_dumpall --column-inserts -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -U UNAME > cluster_backup.sql
```

```bash
pg_dump --column-inserts -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -d DBNAME -U UNAME > db_backup.sql
```

```sql
INSERT INTO public.enduser (id, name) VALUES ('f659b7f9-813a-436b-89e4-e39abcf9fee7', 'asdf');
INSERT INTO public.enduser (id, name) VALUES ('35239537-e1f2-4cd5-8ef2-4dca5a94985c', 'ghij');
INSERT INTO public.enduser (id, name) VALUES ('e48f6e42-10e7-4805-a22d-693c39c56900', 'zxcv');
INSERT INTO public.enduser (id, name) VALUES ('39609d84-fb0f-4acf-adc6-1753f50e905d', 'yuiop');
```

This backup is also better for restoring data to relational databases other than Postgres since the `COPY` command is unique to Postgres.

Another thing to consider is that `pg_dumpall` and `pg_dump` will, by default, create backups that do NOT respect foreign-key constraints since it only applies these constrainst (primary and foreign) in the backup sql script after creating the table without constraints, and copying or inserting the data. This can lead to an issue where, when applying a backup to a database where the table already exists with it's contstraints in place, the foreign-key constraint is not met. This will cause the same error you've mentioned.

To avoid this issue, rather create a data-only backup using the `-a` flag with `pg_dumpall` or `pg_dump`. This will respect foreign-key constraints, and will succeed, even if some of the data is already present in the given tables, if used alongside either the `--inserts` or `--column-inserts` flags. To get a structure-only (schema-only) backup, use the `-s` flag instead of the `-a` flag.

```bash
pg_dumpall -a --inserts -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -U UNAME > cluster_backup.sql
```

```bash
pg_dump -a --inserts -h HNAME -p PNUMBER -d DBNAME -U UNAME > db_backup.sql
```

Yet another solution is to first clean the given tables of all their data before you attempt to write the given data. Practically, this will require backing up the data with the `-Fd` or `-Fc` flags with`pg_dump` (`pg_dumpall` doesn't support this) for a directory-format backup or a custom-format backup respectively, and then restoring it with `pg_restore` using the `-c` (`--clean`) flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the default settings of `pg_dump` and restore. But I think the errors are because you are not dropping and recreating the database on restore.

I would try restoring with `pg_restore` with the `--clean` option (assuming you want to restore from the dump and **not keep anything** in the current db, where you are restoring to. - [user993](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/993/ypercube%e1%b5%80%e1%b4%b9)

Or you can remove the foreign key constraint before restoring and recreate it afterwards.  In a full dump, these are being created *after* the data is loaded into the tables. - [user6219](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6219/dezso)

Also, `pg_dump -Fc` and `pg_restore` are almost always the way to go in preference to using SQL dumps and `psql`. That way you can specify things like `--clean` at load-time. - [user7788](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/7788/craig-ringer)

Answer (score -1):

Try creating new database with empty table with in it and restore the db. The problem probably can be with the existing relation between table.